# Bluemix public - single region availability SLA

Tags: ibm-cloud, availability

Recent [Bluemix terms of use](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/sla/bm-6606-06) document mentions availabilty only for applications deployed across at leas two regions. In the previous versions of Bluemix terms of use (e.g. [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/8bd55c6b9fa8039c86256c6800578854/4e86883e25528c4785257ea5004fb897/$FILE/i126-6605-05_09-2015_en_US.pdf)) there was so called service level objective which was not related to a specific deployment model.

What is Bluemix service availabilty in case I want to deploy my application only in one region?

Comment: I have reposted this question on dW Answers because it is not a technical question. You can find the question here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/246896/bluemix-public-single-region-availability-sla.html

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, the answer was added at:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/246896/bluemix-public-single-region-availability-sla.html